# _CUROBJ not working on Foxpro2.6

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I've try to define the code "_CUROBJ=OBJNUM(m.btn_loc)" to set focus on one button for screen program under setup code section, but It seems to have no effect from starting points. I've missed up maybe certain variable or expression need to be include under screen. May be anyone could give me shoot to this answer.

```
#REGION 1
btn_loc = m.btn_loc
_CUROBJ = OBJNUM(btn_loc)
```

OR

```
 _CUROBJ = 4
```

For inside valid expression, I've put procedure expression as 'BTN_CALL("LOCATE")' and message expression just a Footer showing message.

How I get focus to particular button that I set on screen when execute this screen programs? Thanks appopriate to any helps.

Comment: you reference Foxpro2.6 and Visual Foxpro... which is it, two totally different answers will probably come out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd say it is FoxPro 2.6 for Windows or DOS and I *sincerely* hope that the original poster is not modifying generated screen code and is instead doing the correct thing of modifying the screen using the designer, and then regenerating.

Anyway, what I would do is make the button or button group the first in the screen order via the Screen | Object Order menu option. That will make the button or buttons the highlighted object when the screen opens. Then if the group contains more than one button, designate a default one by including `\!` in the prompt text:

```
\!OK
```